# Open a terminal on Raspberry Pi reboot using crontab

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I have scheduled a python script to run at startup on a Raspberry Pi using crontab. Is there any way to open a terminal or any other way to view what is going on when the Raspberry Pi is booted up? Eg. if an error is occurring it will be seen in the terminal.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write the info to a log file ?

Comment: you can access `/proc/pid/fd/0,1,2` to interact with _stdin_, _stdout_, _stderr_.
But I would agree with the previous comment that makes more sense to write logs.

Comment: I tried using log files but i want to know exactly where the code is going wrong (eg. by periodically printing a message, if one message isn't printed somethings wrong). Log file just shows the error